# How to access cache values in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, caching, spring-cache

Scenario: I need to access the values of a cache created as part of one method in another method. How do I do it?

```
public class Invoice {
  private String invoiced;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  //Getters and Setters
}
```

Method 1: Gets invoked when a customer wants to get list of invoices from UI

```
@Cacheable(value="invoices")
public List<Invoice> getAllInvoices(String customerId){
...
//Get all invoices from Database and return 
...
return invoices
}
```

Method 2: Gets invoked when a customer clicks on download on UI

```
public File downloadInvoice(String invoiceId) {
 //TODO: 
 //Validate if invoiceId is present in the cache. This is a validation step
 //How can I access the cache "invoices" here.
 ...
 //if InvoiceId is present in cache then download from db else throw Exception
 return file;
}
```

Note: I am not using any caching libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotation-enable) (and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-store-configuration)) on *Spring's Cache Abstraction* explains, you must enable caching (i.e. using the `@EnableCaching` annotation with annotation config, or using the `<cache:annotation-driven>` element with XML config) **and** declare a bean of type `CacheManager` to plugin the caching provider of your choice (e.g. Redis).

Of course, when you are using *Spring Boot*, both of these concerns are "*auto-configured*" for you, providing you have declared an appropriate caching provider (i.e. a caching provider implementing *Spring's Cache Abstraction*) on your *Spring Boot* application's classpath.

For complete list of caching providers supported (i.e. "*auto-configured*") by *Spring Boot*, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-caching-provider).

This ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.java)) is *Spring Boot's* caching *auto-configuration* for Redis, when Redis is on the application's classpath.  Notice the [declaration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.java#L55-L68) of the `CacheManager` bean, which must be precisely named "cacheManager".  This setup is the same for all caching providers.

Now that you know you a "cacheManager" bean of type `CacheManager` exists in the *Spring* `ApplicationContext`, you can use the `CacheManager` to [access](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html#getCache-java.lang.String-) the individual caches, which are represented by the [`Cache` (Adapter) interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html).

You could then...

```
@Service
class InvoiceService {

  private CacheManager cacheManager;

  public InvoiceService(CacheManager cacheManager) {
    this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
  }


  public File downloadInvoice(String invoiceId) {

    // Note: name of cache here (i.e. "invoices") must match the name
    // in the `@Cacheable` annotation on getAllInvoices(..).
    Cache invoices = this.cacheManager.getCache("invoices");

    // Now use the "invoices" `Cache` to find a reference to a `Invoice` with "invoiceId".
    // Read/load from database if `Invoice` is "cached"...
    // Do what must be done, etc ...

  }
}
```

However, you have problem.

Your `@Cacheable`, `getAllInvoices(..)` method caches (i.e. maps) "customerId" (key) to a `List<Invoice>` object (value) in the "invoices" cache.

You might be thinking the returned `List` of `Invoices` from your `@Cacheable`, `getAllInvoices(..)` service method are cached individually, by "invoiceId".  However, I assure you, that is NOT the case!

It is actually...

`customerId -> List<Invoice>`

That is, a `List` of `Invoice` objects mapped by the "customerId" in the "invoices" cache.

There are ways to alter the default behavior (e.g. to cache individual `Invoice` objects from the `List` by "invoiceId" in the "invoices" cache if desired, which I have explained in other SO posts on caching Collections), but that is **not** how your application logic is currently setup and will function!

Therefore, you will need to translate the "invoiceId" into a "customerId" to access the `List` of `Invoice` objects from the "invoices" `Cache` by "customerId", and then iterate the `List` to find the (possible) cached `Invoice` by "invoiceId".

Or, you can change your caching logic around (recommended).

Finally...

No caching provider is the same under-the-hood.  There may be a way to access individual caches, independently, depending on provider  However, in general, you should keep in mind that *Spring's* `Cache` representation for the individual caches identified in *Spring's* caching annotations (e.g. `@Cacheable`) or the equivalent JSR-107, JCache API annotation [equivalents](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-jsr-107), are not actual "beans" in the *Spring* Container (unlike the `CacheManager`).

In Redis, caches are Redis HASHES (I believe).

In GemFire/Geode (which I am most familiar with), caches (i.e. `Cache`) is a GemFire/Geode `Region`, which **does** happen to be a *Spring* bean in the `ApplicationContext`.

Also, some caching providers also wrap the underlying data structure (e.g. GemFire/Geode Region) backing the `Cache` with an appropriate template (e.g. `GemfireTemplate`, which is by Region).

I am not certain if (*Sprig Data*) Redis creates a `RedisTemplate` for each HASH backing a `Cache`.  However, this is the case with GemFire/Geode.  So you could do something like this as well...

```
@Service
class InvoiceService {

  @Resource(name = "invoices")
  private Region<String, Invoice> invoices;

  // ...

}
```

Or, alternatively (recommended)...

```
@Service
class InvoiceService {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("invoices")
  GemfireTemplate invoicesTemplate;

  // ... 

}
```

Again, this varies by caching provider and is very provider specific.

The `Cache` Adapter interface is a generic way to reference the backing caching implementation, and useful if you expect to switch caching providers between environments, or for other reasons.

Again, to access the individual caches (e.g. "invoices"), you inject the `CacheManager` since not all caching providers create beans for the individual `Cache` instances.

Remember, you are going to have to change your caching design a bit, I think.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, heaps for the detailed answer. I would only like to differ with you on the part where you say that I need to configure a Cache Provider like Redis in order to access the cache. I have used the default implementation provided by spring, and I was still able to get the value of cache as a [Key, Value] pair from the map, basically this, customerId -> List<Invoice>. I am not using Cacheable, rather I used CachePut as I don't need to use cache for my getInvoices() method. That should be called every time irrespective. Happy to be corrected if my understanding is wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: Most welcome for the detailed answer.  Right, I wasn't implying you needed to use Redis.  I was using Redis (based on popularity) and Geode/GemFire (what I know) as an example.  Again, all I want to say is it varies from provider to provider since the implementation for `Cache` is key (e.g. in GemFire/Geode's case, a `Region`, which is a proper bean in the context).  It is totally possible other providers expose the `Cache` instance as a bean as well.  If they don't, then the main way to get the cached value is by accessing the `Cache` from the `CacheManager`.

Comment: I spoke to `@Cacheable` since the code snippet you shared in your question above made reference/use of `@Cacheable`.  You other statements are likely correct but I only have the code snippets above to go on.  As always, glad to help and hope this moved your forward.  Cheers.

Comment: To clarify 1 point... what I mean by "getting the cached value" is if you are interested in introspecting the cache from inside your application service methods.  Of course, Spring's caching annotation support will return a non-expired, cached value given the same argument(s) (i.e. the cache key) to a cache enabled service method (e.g. a method annotated with `@Cacheable`).  Sorry if this caused confusion.

Comment: It actually cleared all my confusions and helped me move ahead with the code. Thanks again John. Appreciate your time and effort

Answer (score 1):

When you annotate a method as `@Cacheable`, then the first call to that method will store the result of that method in cache. All subsequent calls to this method would return the cached result unless the cache is evicted.

Normal invocation of the `getAllInvoices` will return the  cached results if the results  has been cached previously.

For further reading I would suggest this excellent  [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually my scenario is a bit different. I am not calling getAllInvoices() again. I'm calling downloadInvoice() second time and I need to access the values stored in cache, within downloadInvoice method.

Comment: Is  there a reason why youre not calling getAllInvoices() from the downloadInvoice() method?

Comment: Make sure you're not calling `@Cacheable` method from the same class, therefore it wouldn't work.