# Spring @Cacheable - is it possible to make reads from the cache without making writes to it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I have two micro services and I need one of them to read the cache, but never update it.
I tried to put

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "test-stack", key=..., unless="true")
```

and

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "test-stack", key=..., condition="false")
```

but it didn't work.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: answers in this question could probably help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506999/how-to-access-cache-values-in-spring

Comment: `@Cacheable(..., unless="true")` works for me (`spring-boot:2.7.2`, `spring-core:5.3.22`).

Answer (score 0):

By default, NO.

There is/are no [annotation(s) in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations), or even JCache's API (more generally speaking, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-jsr-107), or specifically [here](https://javadoc.io/static/javax.cache/cache-api/1.1.1/javax/cache/annotation/package-summary.html)) that enables read-only caching behavior.

Fortunately, not all is lost in this case. One of the many benefits of Spring is the ability to extend the current APIs to customize or alter the behavior, for example, caching.

In [Spring's Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache), the 2 primary interfaces of the SPI are the [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) and [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) interfaces in the `org.springframework.cache` package ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/package-summary.html)).

By way of example, and to present 1 possible solution to this problem (off the top of my head) let's assume you are using Redis for caching. As you no doubt already know, without Spring Boot, your application configuration to enable caching would look something like this:

```java
@Conifguration
@EnableCaching
class CachingConfiguration {

  @Bean
  RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Here, you would need to 1) `EnableCaching` and 2) declare a `CacheManager` bean (named "cacheManager") for the caching provider you want to use. Again, in this example we are using Redis.

Now, we are going to introduce a 2nd configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@Profile("read-only-microservice")
class ReadOnlyCachingConfiguration {

  @Bean
  BeanPostProcessor readOnlyCachingBeanPostProcessor() {

    return new BeanPostProcessor() {

      @Override
      public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {

        return bean instanceof CacheManager
          ? new ReadOnlyCacheManager((CacheManager) bean)
          : bean;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

> NOTE: If your application is using multiple caching providers (e.g. Redis and Hazelcast), then the `instanceof` check may need to be altered here depending on your requirements.

Notice 2 things here.

First, notice the use of the Spring `@Profile` annotation. If your microservice is essentially the same application codebase deployed twice with slight configuration differences, then the first microservice can be configured to write to the cache when this profile is disabled (or rather not enabled). However, in the second deployment, you can enable this profile (e.g. as a JVM System property `-Dspring.profiles.active=read-only-microservice`) to disable the microservice from being able to write to the cache.

But, how do you prevent the second deployment of the microservice from writing to the cache?

Well, the second thing to notice here is the "wrapping" (decorating) of the `CacheManager` bean (for example, the `RedisCacheManager`), with the `ReadOnlyCacheManager`.

The `ReadOnlyCacheManager` still implements the `CacheManager` interface, but it essentially wraps and decorates an existing `CacheManager`, such as the `RedisCacheManager`.

The sole purpose of the `CacheManager` is to find/lookup and serve `Cache` objects by "name" when caching operations, such as `@Cacheable` annotated application service methods are called.

So, our implementation would be:

```java
class ReadOnlyCacheManager {


  private final CacheManager source;

  ReadOnlyCacheManager(@NonNull CacheManager cacheManager) {
    Assert.notNull(cacheManager, "CacheManager is required");
    this.source = cacheManager;
  }

  @Override
  public Cache getCache(String name) {

    Cache cache = this.source.getCache(name);

    return cache != null
      ? new ReadOnlyCache(cache);
      : null;
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<String> getCacheNames() {
    return this.source.getCacheNames();
  }
}
```

Pretty straight forward.

Now, you only need to implement the `ReadOnlyCache` implementation that 1) implements the Spring `Cache` interface, 2) wraps the existing `Cache` implementation (e.g. `RedisCache`) and then 3) delegates to the source `Cache` object for the cache operations, except for the write operations (e.g. `put(key, value)`).

For example (partial implementation):

```java
class ReadOnlyCache {

  private final Cache source;

  ReadOnlyCache(@NonNull Cache cache) {
    Assert.notNull(cache, "Cache is required");
    this.source = cache;
  }

  @Override
  public <T> T get(Object key, Class<T> type) {
    return this.source.get(key, type);
  }

  @Override
  public void put(Object key, Object value) {
    // Do Nothing; the Cache is read-only!
  }
}
```

You would override each cache operation appropriately.

You could possible solve this problem other ways as well, such as by injecting your own AOP Aspect into the caching infrastructure. However, you must be careful to order the Aspects correctly.

I prefer the approach I demonstrated above because 1) AOP is a form of "decoration" (or the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)) and 2) this approach is very reliable and will even work with Spring Boot's auto-configuration of caching. With Spring Boot, you do not need to explicitly declare a `CacheManager` bean when you have a caching provider, such as Redis, or 1 of the other [supported caching providers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider) on the classpath and you have enabled caching (i.e. `@EnableCaching`).

If your microservice applications are different (e.g. 2 separate codebases) then you might not need the Profile I demonstrated above.

Anyway, I hope this gives you more ideas on how you can customize the framework to your needs.

I did not explicitly write a test or create an example this time (in my [repository](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers), and specifically [here](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/tree/master/spring-cache)) since I felt this was pretty straight forward. However, I have demonstrated this approach before in other cases. You might find this repository insightful, especially [here](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/tree/master/spring-cache/src/main/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/answers/spring/cache). The `AbstractCacheDelegate` and `AbstractCacheManagerDelegate` help in the process of implementing Spring's `Cache` and `CacheManager` interfaces.

Good luck!